# Couldn't find any package ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb

Tags: ubuntu, ibm-mq

I am trying to install IBM MQ on my Ubuntu.
I want to install a package: `ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb`

I tried both the commands. Nothing seems to work.. I am getting the errors mentioned below in the snippet.

```
trougc@trougc-MacBookPro:~/MQServer$ sudo apt install ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb'
```

And

```
trougc@trougc-MacBookPro:~/MQServer$ sudo dpkg -i ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 222648 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb ...
Entering prerm for "ibmmq-runtime" upgrade 9.0.5.0
Entering preinst for  ibmmq-runtime upgrade 9.0.5.0
ERROR: upgrade operation not supported - please remove previous version
dpkg: error processing archive ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 255
Entering postrm for "ibmmq-runtime" abort-upgrade 9.0.5.0
Entering postinst for ibmmq-runtime abort-upgrade 9.0.5.0
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ibmmq-runtime_9.0.5.0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Ubuntu, but the error seems to indicate you need to remove the prior CD release to install 9.0.5.  `ERROR: upgrade operation not supported - please remove previous version`

Comment: This is the first time I am installing this. But I think I am gonna install different Linux variant which supports rpm.

Comment: `subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 255` see if there is a deb command to extract the "pre-installation" script, you can then see where that may be failing with status 255.  With rpms I have seen things like a extra file in the /var/mqm/qmgrs directory causing problems with the install because it things it is a queue manager and can't stop it or remove ipcs resources.

Comment: This page talks about Ubuntu. You don't need a whole separate OS. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009010_.htm

Comment: I already followed this page. I am stuck at Step 5. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009010_.htm

Comment: Correction: stuck on step 3.